# Evaluation of $~{\mathrm{d}^2 x\over\mathrm{d}t^2}+\left({\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2-4=0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

$$
x=x(t):=C^{\infty}~\text{class function}
$$

$$
\underbrace{\color{red}{{\mathrm{d}^2 x\over\mathrm{d}t^2}+\left({\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2-4=0}
}_{\text{I want to evaluate a general soln of this ODE}}
$$

$$
x(0)={\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}(0)=0
$$

**My tries:**

**NOTICED MISCALCULATION. I AM CORRECTING IT NOW**

$$
\underbrace{{\mathrm{d}^2 x\over\mathrm{d}t^2}+\left({\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2=4
}_{\text{Original ODE}}
$$

$$
\underbrace{{\mathrm{d}^2 x\over\mathrm{d}t^2}+\left({\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2=0
}_{\text{Prepared a new one}}\\
$$

I assume$~{\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\neq0~$
for$~x\neq0$

$$\begin{align}
{\mathrm{d}^2 x\over\mathrm{d}t^2}&=-\left({\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2\\
\left({\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\right)^{-1}{\mathrm{d}^2 x\over\mathrm{d}t^2}&=-\left({\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\right)^1\\
\left({\mathrm{d}t\over\mathrm{d}x}\right){\mathrm{d}^2x\over\mathrm{d}t^2}&=-{\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\\
\int\left(\left({\mathrm{d}t\over\mathrm{d}x}\right){\mathrm{d}^2x\over\mathrm{d}t^2}\right)\mathrm{d}t&=\int-{\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}~\mathrm{d}t\\
\int\left(\left({\mathrm{d}t\over\mathrm{d}x}\right){\mathrm{d}^2x\over\mathrm{d}t^2}\right)\mathrm{d}t&=-x+\text{const}\\
　\left({\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\right)\left({\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\right)　-\int\left(\left({\mathrm{d}t\over\mathrm{d}x}\right){\mathrm{d}^2x\over\mathrm{d}t^2}\right)\mathrm{d}t&=-x+\text{const}
\\
\left({\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2　-\left\{\left({\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2-\int\left(\left({\mathrm{d}t\over\mathrm{d}x}\right){\mathrm{d}^2x\over\mathrm{d}t^2}\right)\mathrm{d}t\right\}&=-x+\text{const}\\
\int\left(\left({\mathrm{d}t\over\mathrm{d}x}\right){\mathrm{d}^2x\over\mathrm{d}t^2}\right)\mathrm{d}t&=-x+\text{const}
\end{align}$$

I've been stucked in the closed loop.

Where I've made (a) mistake(s)?

And how can I evaluate the general solution?

Comment: Wait, I made a mistake of calculation. I will modify it ASAP

Comment: The ODE is nonlinear, there isn't a point to solve the homogeneous equation.

Comment: @TG24: Why not try letting $$x' = p$$

Comment: @Moo I got $~x=\text{const}_1\exp(\sqrt{3}t)+\text{const}_2\exp(-\sqrt{3}t)~$
Is this right?

Comment: It does not look correct. You can check answers by substituting it back in to the DEQ and see if the LHS = RHS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$${\mathrm{d}^2 x\over\mathrm{d}t^2}+\left({\mathrm{d}x\over\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2-4=0$$
Let $u={\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}}$, you have to solve:
$$ u'+u^2= 4 \quad\quad (*)$$
You can solve $(*)$ using separation of variables.

Don't forget to go back to ${\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}}$ integrating $u$ ;).

Comment: I've reached till following. I will take a shower and may response to the answer-posts tommorow.
$$
x=2\int {e^{4t}-1 \over e^{4t}+1 } \mathrm{d}t~~\text{for}~~ {\mathrm{d}x \over \mathrm{d}t }\neq\pm2
$$

Comment: @TG24 seems correct to me, the integral is easy to evaluate with some trick. Is it a problem if the derivative can't be equal to $\pm 2$ or it is from your calculation and you put it for completeness?

Comment: I think that since zero division error occurs below as the derivative is positive or negative 2 so 've written the above but actually the derivative of $~x=\ln\left(\cosh(2t)\right)~$  can't be $~\pm2~$ so I should have removed that statement. 
$$ 
\int{1\over\left(4-u^2\right)}\mathrm{d}u=\int(1)\mathrm{d}t
$$

Comment: @TG24 Yep, I hope I've been helpful

Answer (score 1):

By guessing and looking at the equation, try a solution of the form $x'=a\tanh bt$:

$$ab\operatorname{sech}^2bt+a^2\tanh^2bt -4 =0$$

Choose $a=b=2$ and you get

$$4\operatorname{sech}^2 2t + 4\tanh^2 2t - 4 = 4 - 4 =0$$

Since $\tanh(0)=0$, our solution is

$$x = \int 2\tanh 2t \:dt = \boxed{\log(\cosh 2t)}$$

which satisfies $x(0)=0$.

Comment: Now I've reached the first equation which you've shown above with 2 squared one.

Comment: Finally I've reached to the general soln which you've showed us. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** The substitution $x = \log u$ transforms the initial value problem to a second-order linear i.v.p.

(One way to find this substitution is to observe that the original equation is a Riccati equation in the variable $y := x'$, namely $y' + y^2 - 4 = 0.$ The standard method for solving such equations applies the substitution $y = \frac{u'}{u} = (\log u)'$ to transform the equation into a second-order linear equation.)

> The i.v.p. in $u$ is $$u'' - 4 u = 0, \qquad u(0) = 1, \qquad u'(0) = 0 .$$ The standard method for solving a second-order linear equation with constant coefficients gives the solution  $$u = \cosh 2 t .$$